# firebase.firestore is not a function version 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i wanna use firebase but i constantly get the

> firebase.firestore is not a function

this is my js file where i want to add things to my firebase

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

export function seedDatabase(firebase) {
    function getUUID() {
        // eslint gets funny about bitwise
        /* eslint-disable */
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
            const piece = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
            const elem = c === 'x' ? piece : (piece & 0x3) | 0x8;
            return elem.toString(16);
        });
        /* eslint-enable */
    }

    /* Series
      ============================================ */
    // Documentaries
    firebase.firestore().collection('series').add({
        id: getUUID(),
        title: 'Tiger King',
        description: 'An exploration of big cat breeding and its bizarre underworld, populated by eccentric characters.',
        genre: 'documentaries',
        maturity: '18',
        slug: 'tiger-king',
    }); }
```

this is my js file where i want to connect to my firebase cloud

```
    import { seedDatabase } from "../seed";
/// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
seedDatabase(app)
```

i searched through many stackpages but i didn't find my answer

Comment: You are not importing firebase/firestore correctly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9

Comment: @sychordCoder what should i do here? i just copy all that the firebase gave me

Comment: Read Doug Stevenson answer below. If you are going with Version 9 than you need to follow the correct syntax as he stated. If you want to use version 8 syntax then you need to import the modules/functions using the stated V8 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the version 8 style of API with the version 9 SDK.  That won't work.  The APIs are completely different in v9.

When following the Firebase documentation, you should make sure to use the v9 code samples by selecting the correct tab.  For example, to [add a new document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), the code will look like this:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

// Add a new document with a generated id.
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "series"), {
        id: getUUID(),
        title: 'Tiger King',
        description: 'An exploration of big cat breeding and its bizarre underworld, populated by eccentric characters.',
        genre: 'documentaries',
        maturity: '18',
        slug: 'tiger-king',
});
```

Comment: then how would docRef get invoke for adding ? (i'm just new to use firebase , i'm not trying to be rude)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You don't need to do anything with docRef if you don't want.  addDoc does the adding.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to use version 9 it is configured in this way, you can initialize the configuration You will have to import Cloud Firestore  js/firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

    const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
      apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
      appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    });
```

Initialize Firebase

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseApp);
```

initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service

```
const db = getFirestore(app);
export { db };
```

now in to call the add() method

```
  import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"
    import { db } from "js/firebase.js"; <<< ref
    
    export function seedDatabase() {
      try {
        function getUUID() {
          // eslint gets funny about bitwise
          /* eslint-disable */
          return "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
            const piece = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
            const elem = c === "x" ? piece : (piece & 0x3) | 0x8;
            return elem.toString(16);
          });
          /* eslint-enable */
        }
      
        /* Series
          ============================================ */
        // Documentaries
        const { id } = await addDoc(collection(db, "series"), {
          id: getUUID(),
          title: "Tiger King",
          description:
            "An exploration of big cat breeding and its bizarre underworld, populated by eccentric characters.",
          genre: "documentaries",
          maturity: "18",
          slug: "tiger-king",
        });
    
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
     
    }
```